# Extending table columns in collection view in Plone 4

Tags: collections, plone

Collections provide an option to select columns to be display within the table view of collection.

We are extending most content-types with two fields using archetypes.schemaextender: teaser image and teaser text.

- Is there a sane way to extend the list of available table columns?
- Is there a way to display the teaser text and teaser image inside the table view of the collection with out further customization? Is the logic of the table view flexible enough in order to support a schema extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [collective.formcriteria](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.formcriteria/).  I haven't polished it nearly enough and installing it can get you in some uninstall trouble so don't install it without first backing everything up.  That said, it gives you more than enough rope to do what you want using column expressions.  Of course this is also more than enough rope to hang yourself with.

Answer (score 6):

In the control panel -> collections ( typically /portal_atct/atct_manageTopicIndex) you can define every metadata you need. Collections depends on portal_catalog metadata and indexes, so you've to add your custom fields there. Use GenericSetup in your module profile to tell ZCatalog to create the new indexes, or create them by hand. In the former case, beware that reinstalling the module could wipe out the new created indexes ( http://maurits.vanrees.org/weblog/archive/2009/12/catalog ).

Comment: Unusable answer: neither does this work for images nor does it work for TextFields containing HTML snippets nor does it work for special indexed columns where the rendering involves some special logic -> Downvote

Comment: provide an "usable" answer then :) we're talking of collections tabular results, so no way to make it too generic.

Comment: Yuri gave the right answer.  There's no reason to be rude just because your use-case apparently exceeds the capacities of Plone.

Comment: I don't think there's a possible way of showing HTML or image inside a collection table unless you store the whole HTML snippet in the catalog as metadata, which is not advisable. Anyway, @yuri's answer is right to provide additional columns in a collection table.