# How do I add my own custom metadata for creating a custom collection in Plone 4.1?

Tags: python, plone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extending table columns in collection view in Plone 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455250/extending-table-columns-in-collection-view-in-plone-4)

I wish to add Metadata other than the default Plone Metadata. Eg Fields like customer name, product code etc as new fields criteria for creating the collections view. How do I add my own custom metadata for creating a custom collection in Plone 4.1?

Comment: this question has already been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455250/extending-table-columns-in-collection-view-in-plone-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second answer here: [Extending table columns in collection view in Plone 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455250/extending-table-columns-in-collection-view-in-plone-4) can help you. You've to add indexes and metadata in the catalog (go to zmi -> portal_catalog and use the Indexes and Metadata tabs) and the use the plone control panel to assign those new fields to collections. This is the full answer:

"In the control panel -> collections ( typically /portal_atct/atct_manageTopicIndex) you can define every metadata you need. Collections depends on portal_catalog metadata and indexes, so you've to add your custom fields there. Use GenericSetup in your module profile to tell ZCatalog to create the new indexes, or create them by hand. In the former case, beware that reinstalling the module could wipe out the new created indexes ( http://maurits.vanrees.org/weblog/archive/2009/12/catalog )."